# Evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{3k}{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Not exactly sure how to approach. Cannot do telescoping, or break up the sum into two parts either, cannot find a way to express division as the sum here. Although, if it was something like $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ we could write $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Would like to solve this with simple/clever arithmetic.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your profile: $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}\ne -i$

Comment: :) $i^2 = -1$ :)

Comment: But your profile says that $i^i=-1$, not $i^2=-1$.

Comment: oh dear me, thanks for pointing out. I looked like uninitiated all this time

Comment: No problem! :) $\space$

Comment: $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{3k}{2^k}=3\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2^k}
$$

OK- for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k}$ I needed a bit help from [WolframAlpha][1]:
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k}=2
$$

  [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Binfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7B2%5Ek%7D

Comment: @KrzysztofMyśliwiec that is the content of the problem, and it is generally solved by differentiating the series below

Comment: @qbert I got an idea today: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{1+2}{2^3}+\frac{2^2}{2^4}+\frac{1+2^2}{2^5}+\frac{2+2^2}{2^6}+\frac{1+2+2^2}{2^7}+\frac{2^3}{2^8}+\frac{1+2^3}{2^9}+...=$
$\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^7}+\frac{1}{2^9}+...+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^6}+...=> ? 2 \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$ .

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Consider the series of functions

$$\sum \frac{x^k}{2^k}$$

and its derivative.

Comment: I know I can use L'Hopitals here, but this is the school programme, so should be solvable without derivatives :)